# Joining two identical OBJ's with different UV maps

Tags: uv, obj

I'm working with some model exported from a game (for the purpose of modding), however the current model exporter can only export to OBJ, losing any extra UV maps.

If i somehow managed to get the model exported multiple times, one for each different UV map, would it be possible to combine those multiple identical meshes into one, but have all the UV's remain separate?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by using [Copy UV Maps](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/link_transfer/copy_uvmaps.html). Note that to work the models must have identical geometry (ie. the indices need to be the same), which basically means your OBJ files will need to be identical besides for the UVs.

The procedure is:

1. Import one model, call it A.
2. Create a second UV Map on A and rename it to what you want. This UV Map needs to be selected.
3. Import the second model with different UVs, call it B.
4. In Object mode, deselect everything. Then select A, then B. (This means A is selected and B is active.)
5. Run Object > Link/Transfer Data > Copy UV Maps.
6. Check that the second UV Map on A contains the UVs from B.
7. You can delete B now.